# How can I create apps developed using Jquery mob/ Sencha touch that runs in iPhones & simulators

Tags: objective-c, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios4, sencha-touch

I am basically an Iphone developer and I would like to study Jquery mobile or Sencha Touch for building some apps.I have downloaded Jquery mob and sencha touch sdks but How can I create apps with that which runs in iPhones & simulators.How can I integrate Jquery mob or Sencha to my Xcode?Can you please tell me the basic deployment steps  for installing either sencha touch or Jquery mobile in my Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Use PhoneGap

http://phonegap.com/

I have used JQuery Mobile myself, and I used it with PhoneGap, there are tutorials online on the website to show you how to set it up.

Edit: Link to the set up page

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Edit2:

http://jquerymobile.com/resources/

PhoneGap – tool to wrap jQuery Mobile code for native app deployment

Comment: Is it not possible to create Apps in Jquery mobile without the help of phone gap?I mean is it possible to work Jquery mobile in Xcode?What are the basic steps of creating a Jquery mobile app? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not that I am aware of, see my 2nd edit. Follow the tutorials online for PhoneGap to set it up, creating apps in JQueryMobile is pretty easy to begin with